# File Storage usage with Django and Amazon S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3, storage, boto, django-storage

I have a scenario where storage use needs to be determined in my app by user since it will be placing limits on how much storage can be used. I'm currently using django-storage, boto, and S3 to manage and store files. What is the best way to aggregate storage use on a per user basis?

I thought about keeping track of each file that's uploaded, incrementing the file size on upload/decrementing on delete, and storing that aggregated file size in the DB, but I'm wondering if there is a way to get this more cleanly. What solutions have others done out there? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a full solution, but a start might be to store the user-uploaded fields in folders that are specific to the user. The "upload_to" attribute of a model field can be a callable that returns the location to store the media; this could end up putting users' uploads into user-specific buckets within your S3 storage.

Then you can use boto (or other tools) to query for the size of a user's bucket.

Comment: That seems like a good solution. I'm wondering if boto needs to iterate through all the keys in a user specific bucket and if that would be a memory intensive execution. I'll give this a try...thanks!